# Add & load a jquery tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I have a jquery tabs object which starts with one tab defined. That tab displays a table of data, and I want that clicking on an item in the table creates a new tab and loads content via ajax. So pretty dynamic.

So far I have a function that I call from an onclick event from the first tab. The function adds a new tab. Next, I tried to set a url but that doesn't work. How do I do this?

```
function addTab() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "add", "#tabs-x", "New Tab" );
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "url" , 1 , "http://mysite.com/details.php" );
}
```

Note that I will be passing an id parameter to the addTab function and in turn to the url, but I just wanna get these initial mechanics down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change an *existing* remove tab with the `url` method, so you'd need to have it remote initially, like this:

```
function addTab() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "add", "http://mysite.com/temp", "New Tab" );
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "url" , 1 , "http://mysite.com/details.php" );
}
```

Or just set it initially when adding would be simpler:

```
function addTab() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "add", "http://mysite.com/details.php", "New Tab" );
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see that now in the documentation; I misunderstood some sample source code. Follow-up question, if I may: I see that as I switch between tabs, the new tab always goes out and reloads itself. Can I prevent that? Once it's loaded, it can be considered static.

Comment: @eflat - you could change the url to a non-ajax one after a load, make it match the created tab Id itself